# How to bring a frame forward (like Printer machine window) when clicked during execution of my application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8, swingx

I have an application written in Java. I want to bring a frame forward (appearing in front) when it is clicked upon during the execution of my application.
Just like the Printer machine window can do.

Here is an image to clarify the problem:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question. I hope it is more clear now. There are a few things you could do to improve it. First, please include a [mcve] of the code you have now. With that, we may be able to help you better. You can [edit] it into your post. Second, please clarify - do you want another frame to come forward, or the frame of your program? Is the frame that is in front now something from your program, or from someone else's program?

Comment: Also - you speak of Java Netbean. I _suppose_ you mean the NetBeans IDE, but your IDE should not matter for this. However, if you mean this program involves a Java Bean or Enterprise Java Bean, you should add that to the question. The better people can understand your problem, the better the chance that they can help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. Clicking on a frame should automatically focus it to the front layer by default. I made a quick test to make sure:

```
    JFrame frameOne = new JFrame();
    frameOne.setBounds(200, 50, 600, 700);
    frameOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frameOne.setVisible(true);

    JFrame frameTwo = new JFrame();
    frameTwo.setBounds(600, 50, 600, 700);
    frameTwo.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frameTwo.setVisible(true);
```

It works fine. Clicking on either frame brings it to the front if it's not already in the front.

Unless I'm reading the question wrong and this is not what you were asking?

Comment: second one window frame is not our application frame here whatever you answered that may be valid for our own application's frame but not for another JFrame.